# TimeSpan's comparison is so slow

Tags: c#, .net, performance

Recently I had one strange performance problem. 
I need to compare time intervals in cycle with large amount of iterations. 
I used DateTime.TimeOfDay property to compare these intervals. However, I found that these comparisons are very slow versus DateTime comparisons. So, I had to create DateTime's with 1 year 1 month and 1 day to speed up time' intervals comparison's.
I prepared a small example to show what I mean.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DatesBenchmark
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            DateTime firstDate = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime secondDate = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5);
            for (int i = 0; i < 2000000; i++)
            {
                var a = firstDate.TimeOfDay > secondDate.TimeOfDay;
                //var a = firstDate > secondDate;
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I got 15ms (if first row in for cycle is commented) versus 176 ms (if second row in for cycle is commented) on my laptop.

My question is short. Why?

Comment: Why do you care?  176ms over 2*million* records is nothing.

Comment: This is simplified example. In my real application a lot of time comparisons and I really feel this difference.

Comment: 176ms is an enormous amount of time when building a high-performance routine, and 2 million records isn't that much data. Whether it *matters* is a completely different question, but it's not a trivial amount of time or an unreasonable amount of data.

Comment: Modulo operations are expensive. Especially 64 bit modulo in a 32 bit application. Switch your application to 64 bit, for a factor 3 performance boost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling foo.TimeOfDay is doing this:

```
public TimeSpan TimeOfDay
{
    get
    {
        return new TimeSpan(this.InternalTicks % 864000000000L);
    }
}
```

By accessing the `TimeOfDay` property on 2 `DateTime` instances over 2 million iterations you are creating 4 million `Timespan` instances. However, that's not the biggest expense.

Digging further, you have:

```
internal long InternalTicks
{
    get
    {
        return (long)(this.dateData & 4611686018427387903uL);
    }
}
```

So you have 4 million instantiations, remainder calculations, casts, and `&` operations. These are all cheap operations ("cheap" of course being a relative term) but done in quantity they add up.

The actual comparison is trivial:

```
public static bool operator >(TimeSpan t1, TimeSpan t2)
{
    return t1._ticks > t2._ticks;
}
```

Compiling the OPs code in Debug mode, I see:

1. Empty loop: 4ms.
2. `var a = firstDate > secondDate;` 6ms (suggesting it is not optimized away)
3. `var a = firstDate.TimeOfDay;` 40ms
4. `var a = firstDate.TimeOfDay > secondDate.TimeOfDay;` 80ms
5. `TimeSpan a = new TimeSpan( ticks ), b = new TimeSpan( ticks );` 7ms

Running a performance analysis in VS 2012 against the program, 81% of samples are coming from `DateTime.get_TimeOfDay()`.

Running x64, Release mode, all optimizations enabled:

1. Empty loop: 3ms.
2. `var a = firstDate > secondDate;` 6ms
3. `var a = firstDate.TimeOfDay;` 20ms
4. `var a = firstDate.TimeOfDay > secondDate.TimeOfDay;` 40ms
5. `TimeSpan a = new TimeSpan( ticks ), b = new TimeSpan( ticks );` 6ms

So:

- Micro-benchmarks can be misleading (though not useless).
- Enable optimizations before deciding there is a problem.
- Performance appears to double with optimization.
- The statements in question do not appear to be optimized away under any circumstance.
- Instantiation is a tangible but minor part of the expense.
- Cast/arithmetic operations account for the rest of the expense.
- Storing the property value in a variable before looping greatly improves performance.

Comment: Given that `TimeSpan` is a struct, creating lots of instances of it is not at all expensive.

Comment: The performance hit is that the `TimeSpan` part of OP's test app is actually getting run while the `DateTime` comparison is not.

Comment: @Servy - I updated my answer a bit. Also, I agree that instantiating 4 million structs isn't that big of a hit, but it's certainly slower than creating 2 structs and comparing them.

Comment: @TimMedora Yes, but not to enough of a degree to result in the times seen by the OP.  Comparing the times will be slower, but not 160ms slower.

Comment: In my real application I called TimeOfDay property very frequently. So, it seems to be that the root of problem is actually in instantiation of TimeSpan's.

Comment: @eternity - the instantiation seems to account for about 60% of the time, and the remainder, cast, and bitwise op account for the rest. So yes, accessing `TimeOfDay` over and over does appear to be the cause of the problem.

Comment: For the instantiation cost, you should instantiate from ticks, since that's what `TimeOfDay` needs. I don't think the instantiation (whatever that means in the first place) is the biggest cost. Calculating the remainder is.

Comment: @CodesInChaos - you are correct, that actually alters the numbers on that instantiation significantly. I'll update for accuracy.

Answer (score 5):

You are never using `a`, so in the second case the compiler can optimize the entire statement away since it causes no side effects and the variable is never used.  In the first case it can't be sure that the property called on the date time doesn't cause side effects (the optimization analysis isn't that in depth) and so the line needs to remain.

On top of that, there is at least *some* computation involved in determining the time of day (it needs to mod the number of ticks in the date time by the number of ticks in a day) which mean it will be slower, it's just a question of how much.